# What is "tad askew"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

> Seinfeld, "[The Raincoats](http://www.seinology.com/scripts/script-82and83.shtml)."
>
> (Jerry and Elaine sitting in the booth)
>
> ELAINE: N-I know they're your parents Jerry an' they're very nice
> people. But don't you think it's odd, that a thirty-five year old man
> is going to these lengths to see that someone else's parents are
> enjoying themselves? I mean don't you find that abnormal?
>
> JERRY: It is a **tad askew**.

What does it mean here?

Comment: I love this show. Good choice for learning English. Don't forget about learning "regifting", "soup Nazi", and "spongeworthy".

Comment: @bittenfig: Oh, you'd better believe it, buddy.

Comment: @bittenfig, Graduate: That's debatable. The current item (and doubtless many more from the same stable) are written by highly-paid scriptwriters targeting native speakers with what may often be quirky usages intended to amuse. They're definitely *not* in the business of helping non-native speakers gain insights into "normal, current usages".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: That's true, they do use "slang." But this TV show (at least for me) has a property that overcomes other drawbacks -- it's gripping. It is interesting to watch every episode many times, and then repeat the scenes in your head including what the characters said. And by this repeated process digest the language.

Comment: @Graduate: Well, there's no denying that if something holds your interest at the "foreground" level (the story, for example) you're *much* more likely to absorb "background" information (specifically for a learner, the *language*). And of course, even if the language doesn't always reflect current natural usage, sometimes things from TV shows catch on and become far more widespread. But you have to remember it's basically stylised entertainment - no more "natural language" than The Simpsons, or a Bond movie (or my current favourite, [Archer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archer_(TV_series))).

Comment: A number of phrases from Seinfeld *did* enter the popular lexicon while the show was airing.  I'm not sure how many of them are still with us, though.  (I, being tragically unhip, am probably the wrong person to answer that question.  :-)  I never saw Seinfeld in the first place, so all my Seinfeld vocabulary is secondhand.)

Comment: @snailplane: The phrase "*yadda, yadda, yadda*" was first used in Seinfeld and now is widespread.

Comment: @Graduate Ah, I think that particular phrase predates Seinfeld, but the show certainly did introduce a lot of others.  I remember people saying "master of my domain" and then giggling, for example :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the combination of ***a tad*** (meaning "a little" or "slightly") and ***askew*** (meaning "not quite straight; off to one side or the other").  Here, ***askew*** is used figuratively to mean "not quite normal".  Jerry is agreeing with Elaine that it is a little bit abnormal.

> It is [ [ a tad ] askew ] .

The entire phrase ***a tad*** acts like an adverb here, modifying ***askew***.  The phrase ***tad askew*** does not form a noun phrase, even though it looks like it does.  I suspect that this is the source of your confusion.

Comment: I don't think _askew_ is used in this context very often, and suspect the script was written that way for humorous effect. I would usually say, "That's a little strange," (or even, "That's a bit bizarre,") instead of, "That's a tad askew" – unless I was trying to be a tad comical.

Comment: I would say the cited usage is itself "a little bit abnormal", or at least [somewhat facetiously "folksy"](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/18850/2637) (as I see J.R. has also commented, before I hit "Add Comment"! :)